# Increase PDF Size in iOS WebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I am trying to increase the font size of a PDF that I simply load using UIWebView.  I set up a slider, and in the implementation put in:

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%f%%'",
                          self.theslider.value];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:self.theslider.value forKey:@"fontsize"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    [jsString release];

}
```

This works with regular pages, but doesn't do anything for the PDF.  Any suggestions on what I can do?  Zooming the web page works, but gets text out of frame of view when enlarged to a certain point.  Changing font would at least allow it to all stay in frame.

Comment: This doesn't work because internal PDF data doesn't just contain your HTML with the respective tags and ids. This means you can't simply perform JavaScript code on PDF data even though you can use UIWebView to display your PDF.
Not sure what to do here either, just wanted to share some perspective